# Returned value in delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I got AudioView class with protocol and init method

```
 @protocol AudioViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)playButtonAction:(id)sender;  //(1)
- (void)playButtonActionforAudioTrack:(AudioTrack *)audioTrack;   //(2)
```

////

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame forAudioTrack:(AudioTrack *)audioTrack withButtonTag:(int)buttonTag
```

I init class with audio track. I have play button and then I tap it on screen, in delegate in method (1) I get sender tag of tapped button.

How can I return audioTrack in delegate for played track?

=========================
Class

```
 @protocol AudioViewDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)playButtonAction:(id)sender;
 - (void)playButtonActionforAudioTrack:(AudioTrack *)audioTrack;
 @end

 @interface AudioView : UIView

 @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *audioTitle;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *durationTitle;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *playButton;

 @property (nonatomic, weak) id <AudioViewDelegate> delegate;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame forAudioTrack:(AudioTrack *)audioTrack withButtonTag:(int)tag;
```

//.m

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame forAudioTrack:(AudioTrack *)audioTrack withButtonTag: (int)buttonTag
 {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.frame = frame;
    self.tag = 0011;

    UIImageView *audioImageView = ..
    //[audioView addSubview:audioImageView];

    self.playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.playButton.frame = audioImageView.frame;
    self.playButton.tag = buttonTag;
    [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:audioImageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:self.playButton];


    [self.playButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(playButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.audioTitle = ..
    self.audioTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", audioTrack.artist, audioTrack.title];
    [self addSubview:self.audioTitle];

    self.durationTitle = ..
    [self addSubview:self.durationTitle];


}
return self;
```

}

////delegate

Creating View

```
                 for (NSDictionary *dic in audioArray)
    {
        AudioTrack *audioTrack = [[AudioTrack alloc]init];
        audioTrack.artist = dic[@"artist"];
        audioTrack.title = dic[@"title"];
        audioTrack.duration = dic[@"duration"];
        audioTrack.url = dic[@"url"];
        [self.audioArray addObject:audioTrack];

             AudioView *audioView = [[AudioView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, currentHeight + audioInset, 300, 20) forAudioTrack:audioTrack withButtonTag:[audioArray indexOfObject:dic]];
        audioView.delegate = self;
        [view addSubview:audioView];
```

/// implementing delegate

```
  - (void)playButtonAction:(id)sender
 {
int audioTag = [sender tag]; //here I get tag of tapped button
AudioTrack *sectedTrack = [self.audioArray objectAtIndex:audioTag];
```

I find track with vary long way. Is it possible that I get tapped audioTrack in delegate?

Comment: How should we know. Show a bit more code of the class that implements the protocol and the class that uses the delegate.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker, I add full code

Comment: @Hermann Klecker, and look please for my comment for rmaddy post

Comment: I cannot see your comment on maddy's post. I get an error message from stack overflow instead.

Comment: Well, where do you actually call playButtonAction? Looking at it I got a guts felling that you mixed up a delegate with the action method of a view.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker, playButtonAction runs in delegate and in it I get tag of audioView

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but it is far to long for a comment.

Well, if A is a class that wants to send messages to objects of other classes that it uses as delegate then it is wise, as you did, to declare a protocol for all the methods in other classes, that A wants to call. 
Lets call it ProtocolA and the methods method1 and method2. method2 receives an int as parameter. 
Then you have any other class B or C or whatever, that conforms to the protocol ProtocolA. Then it is usual having a variable of type id  in A with the name delegate. At some point in time, when you want to send the message, then you call [self.delegate method1];

That is basically all about the delegation pattern. Where do you call playButtonAction: ?

Comment: In my custom class I have View with button. Then in UI I tap this button in delegate runs playButtonAction: and I receive tag of custom View class.  (I can have 0-10 such instances of this class and I need to know that sound play in delegate). So, correctly question is: I have custom class with custom property A. I have delegate VC for this class. I want receive property A from delegate method in delegate VC. How can I send to delegate the object?

Comment: You get the tag already. Obviously you got a self.audioArray which delivers the track for the given index (that you have in the tag property). What else do you need?

Comment: yep, I am interesting, is it possible to create protocol method that will return audio track to delegate then button tapped?

Comment: It is possible to create a protocol method for nearly everything. That is what protocols are made for.

Comment: how can I do it? i have no idea

Comment: I am afraid explaining coding principles like the delegation pattern is far beyond the scope of SO.